# ActiveRecord::Base extending with ClassMethods module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a code like this in rails console:

```
module Taggable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    module ClassMethods
      def taggable?
        false
      end
    end
end
```

> When I run: `ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, Taggable`. I see that the method taggable? will become instance_methods of singleton_class: `ActiveRecord::Base.singleton_class.instance_methods.include? :taggable? # => true`.
>
> But when I run `ActiveRecord::Base.extend Taggable`. I don't know where is the method taggable? in? `ActiveRecord::Base.singleton_class.methods.include? :taggable? # => false`

Please help me understand it.

Comment: Which Ruby version ? 2.0 or 2.1 ?

Comment: I use version  2.1 @Sharvy Ahmed